# How to get taxonomy term by description, programatically

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, hooks

In a D7 custom module, I wish to retrieve a taxonomy term by it's description (and not it's name or TID).

Right now I do have it working, but I feel the code is a bit clunky, and I feel like there is a more elegant / Drupally way of doing it.

Is there a better way of doing it then this?

```
$vocabulary = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load('my_vocabulary');
$terms = entity_load('taxonomy_term', FALSE, array('vid' => $vocabulary->vid));

foreach ($terms as $term) {
  if ($term->description == 'my_term_description') {
    // Do stuff when there is a match.
  }
}
```

Ideally, I feel like there is a better way I cannot find through Google / Drupal API etc. Something like:

```
$term = taxonomy_by_description_load('my_vocabulary', 'my_term_description');
```

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the EntityFieldQuery (this is untested)

```
  $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
  $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'taxonomy_term')
    ->entityCondition('bundle', array('my_vocabulary'))
    ->propertyCondition('description', 'my_term_description');
  $result = $query->execute();
  $tids = array_keys($result['taxonomy_term']);

  return $tids;
```

More information https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules/howtos/how-to-use-entityfieldquery-for-drupal-7

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I don't have enough rep points to vote for an answer to my own question :(